# Weird result on nodejs scan list query for aerospike?

Tags: node.js, aerospike

Is there something wrong here?
I have this snippet and it shows all the record on my stream?
The statement filters seemed to be not ignored.

I have the secondary index already setup.

// bin type for uid is text

```
var statement = { 
    concurrent: true,
    nobins: false,
};

statement.filters = [aerospike.filter.equal("idx_mynamespace_myset_uid", "639085555553")];

var query = client.query('mynamespace','myset', statement);

var stream = query.execute();
var count = 0;

stream.on('data', function(rec) {
// process the scanned record here
  count++;
  console.log(rec);
});

stream.on('error', function(err){
    // console.log(err);
});

stream.on('end', function() {
    console.log('TOTAL SCANNED:', count++);
    process.exit(0)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

New version of Aerospike's Node.js Client (1.0.31) has fixes for equal and range queries. However, please note that range queries on strings are not supported or recommended and using them may result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Meku: did Aerospike's Node.js Client version 1.0.31 solve your problem?